# cachemanager.net - How to get List of objects from redis cache based on key passed?

Tags: caching, redis, cachemanager

How do I get a List of objects from redis cache based on the key passed?

I am exploring cachemanager.net for redis cache. I have gone through the examples. But I could not find any example related to getting the List of objects based on the key passed.

```
var lst =cache.Get("Key_1");
```

It is returning only one object.

But I would like it like this. I have stored 1000 objects in cache with key name like `Key_1`, `Key_2`, `Key_3`..... `Key_1000`. I want to get list of 1000 objects if I pass `Key_*` as Key.

Answer (score 2):

CacheManager does not provide any functionality to search keys or get many keys via wildcard. That's simply not how caches work.

As Karthikeyan pointed out, in Redis you could use the `keys` operator, but that's not a good solution and should only be used for debugging manually. Other cache systems don't even have something like that, therefore CacheManager also cannot provide that feature. Hope that makes sense ;)

With CacheManager, you can either store all your objects in one cache key and cache the list. That might have some limitations if you use redis because serialization might be become an issue.

Or, you store each object separately and retrieve them in a loop. The redis client will optimize certain things, also, in CacheManager, if you have 2 layers of caching, the performance will get better over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis hash instead. And you can use hgetall command to retrieve all the values in that hash.

http://redis.io/commands#hash

Or if you want to use a normal key Value pair you have to write a lua script to achieve it.

```
local keys = redis.call('keys','key_*')
return redis.call('mget',keys)
```

Keys is not advisable in production as it is blocking.

You can use scan command instead of keys to get all the keys matching that pattern and then follow the same procedure to achieve the same.